# Returning different tables based on parameter?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, parameters, return

For example, I have a function that returns a table with columns as follows:

`RETURNS TABLE (a CHARACTER VARYING, b BOOLEAN, c NUMERIC)`

Then based on a parameter `result_mode DEFAULT 'SUMMARY'`, I want it to return a different table like as follows:

```
RETURNS TABLE (a TIMESTAMPTZ, b BOOLEAN, c CHARACTER VARYING, d NUMERIC)
```

Originally I have this stored procedure in MS SQL that could return the results by 'SUMMARY', 'CUSTOMER ITEM SUMMARY', 'ITEM SUMMARY' etc. However in Postgresql, its different I think.

I might need to create multiple functions if I can't fit them into one single function.

So, is it possible to sort of have an if-statement or case statement that returns the table based on a parameter input?

Comment: are you using Microsoft SQL Server or postgresql ?

Comment: I'm converting stored procedures from Microsoft SQL Server into Postgresql functions.